# How to do css in JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, styled-components

I am new to JavaScript . I don't have much knowledge related to JavaScript Object . Actully I want to convert CSS properties to JavaScript Object . I code for one css properties which is working fine but I face some logic problem . I will give you code I want to convert these two properties in JavaScript object .

**React Component**

```
<div className="left-menus">
      {menus.map(item => {
          return (
            <Link to={item.name} name={item.name} key={item.name}
              className={this.state.activeMenu === item.name ? 'menu active' : 'menu' }
              onClick={() => this.setState({ activeMenu: item.name })}
              >
              <Icon name={item.icon} size="large"/>
              <span>{item.name}</span>
            </Link>
          )
      })}
    </div>
```

**JavaScript Object**

```
leftMenu : {
    position: 'fixed',
    width: '200px',
    paddingRight:' 0 !important',
    backgrounColor: '#fff',
    height: '100%',
    marginTop: '20px',
    top: '47px',
    fontSize: '12px !important',
    borderRight: '2px solid #e8e8ec'
}
```

**App.CSS**

```
         .left-menus {
          position: fixed;
          width: 200px;
          padding-right: 0 !important;
          background-color: #fff;
          height: 100%;
          margin-top: 20px;
          top: 47px;
          font-size: 12px !important;
          border-right: 2px solid #e8e8ec; }
          .left-menus .menu {
            color: #4a4a4a;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-transform: capitalize !important;
            padding: 15px 10px 15px 18px; 
          }
```

I created object for css property which name as `left-menus` but I have problem to create logic for second properties because second properties implement some vales of Ist property . Someone Please help me how to do this task. 
Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You already have the css, just import the stylesheet into your code. You can't apply css to a component from it's parents styles.

Comment: Please explain 'second properties implement some values of first property'. I don't see that happening.

Comment: @SpeedOfRound Not true, in React you could pass element's style as javascript object.

Comment: As a prop? Sure, I guess, but you shouldn't.

Comment: @SpeedOfRound As a standard prop, yes. Didn't say it's recommended way, but it is possible :p

Comment: @SpeedOfRound Could you please Implement this two values ?

Comment: @Jon would need to see your react component to be able to help more.

Comment: @SpeedOfRound I updated My Question . There I updated React Component . Please have a look . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like everything is all right, except variable declaration maybe. 
Is this something you would like to achieve?

```
const divStyle = {
  color: 'blue',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
};

function HelloWorldComponent() {
  return <div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How to Implement second properties like `.left-menus .menu`

Comment: Excatly the same, you isolate it in another variable?

Comment: Could you please write code for these two properties of CSS ( I am confusing about it because I am beginner ) Thanks

Comment: Because we are targeting two Descendant Combinator of css

Answer (score 0):

I can't gurantee it will work as is since I don't know what `Link` and `Icon` is, but it would look something like this:

```
<div className="left-menus" style={{
  position: 'fixed',
  width: '200px',
  paddingRight: ' 0 !important',
  backgrounColor: '#fff',
  height: '100%',
  marginTop: '20px',
  top: '47px',
  fontSize: '12px !important',
  borderRight: '2px solid #e8e8ec'
}}>
  {menus.map(item => {
    return (
      <Link to={item.name} name={item.name} key={item.name}
        className={this.state.activeMenu === item.name ? 'menu active' : 'menu'}
        onClick={() => this.setState({ activeMenu: item.name })}
        style={{
         color: '#4a4a4a',
         width: '100%',
         display: 'block',
         cursor: 'pointer',
         textTransform: 'capitalize !important',
         padding: '15px 10px 15px 18px',
      }}
>
        <Icon name={item.icon} size="large" />
        <span>{item.name}</span>
      </Link>
    )
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to use CSS Inline . I want to work on Descendant Combinator of css through JavaScript Object . Could you please help me how to write Javascript object that target two properties of css

Comment: @Jon you can do descendent combinators inside the styled-components string template. as far as i know, you can't with react, javascript style objects

Answer (score -1):

Try https://www.styled-components.com/ you can write something like, it's only js :

```
const Button = styled.a`
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.5rem 1rem;
  width: 11rem;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
`

render(
  <div>
    <Button
      href="https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components"
      target="_blank"
      rel="noopener"
      primary
    >
      GitHub
    </Button>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I tried but Not able to implement two properties of CSS Like (.left-menus .menu)